# address standardizer code in python for street featureclass

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

In my system I have featureclass Street and having fields.

Featureclass : Street

Input fields: NAME;STREET_PREFIX;STREET_NAME;STREET_TYPE;STREET_SUFFIX

output fields: ADDR_PD;ADDR_PT;ADDR_SN;ADDR_ST;ADDR_SD

I want to standardize input fields and values should goto output fields. 
But how to create standardizer address scripts for above featureclass
in which we are having input and outfields in same featureclass.

database ins orcale 11g and pyhton2.6.5

[image]

Comment: Hi Tarun, you may be interested in testing out this python package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/usaddress.  I don't have much experience with it, but saw it mentioned in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143781/how-do-i-get-items-from-ordereddict-to-parse-addresses

Answer (score 2):

Like many GIS projects, there are a couple phases to this task. First, you must get to know your data. Once you know what you are working with, you can create your automation to achieve your goal.

To standardize data, first you need to know all of your starting values. It looks like the field Street Type is the field in question in this particular exercise, so I'll focus on that.

In ArcGIS, with your roads layer in your table of contents, open your python window. It's on your Standard toolbar.

Use a little code like this to get to know your unique values:

`roadTypes = list(set([rd for rd in arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("Street_Centerline", "Street Type")]))`

Then:

```
for type in roadTypes:
    print type
```

Now you have all your different road types printed out. You'll need to take some time to figure out how you want to group your road types. For example, find all the values you want to convert to RD.

If you have excel, I would copy and paste your printed values into excel to make the data easy to work with.

This is where you get to be a bit creative. For example, remember there is the method `.upper ()` for strings that allows you to ignore cases. Also, if you notice all values that start with the letter 'R' are roads, you can use the method `.startswith ("R")`

Once you have all of your groups together it's time to write your final code to convert your data. The field calculator in ArcGIS would work well for this task, but since you asked for the work in python I'll give you the basics.

You can an `UpdateCursor`, but we'll use `CalculateField_management` here. `CalculateField_management` will need five inputs - your feature class, the field to calculate, an expression, the type of expression, and a codeblock. The first two are easy, the last three are a bit trickier.

Since our code block and expression will be python code, we'll use `"PYTHON_9.3"` for the type of expression. Our codeblock will consist of defining a function. The function is where you need to create a series of `if/elif/else` statements that suit your data. Finally, your expression will call the function. In the code below I capitalize values I pass to the function to make things easier.

Code (untested):

```
import arcpy

#Path to roads feature class
roadsFC = r"{Feature\class\full\path}"

#Field to calculate
calcFld = "Std Street Type"

#Field to analyze
anFld = "Street Type"

#Code block
codeblock = """
def Standardize_Road_Type (inVal):
    if inVal.startswith ("R"):
        return "RD"
    elif inVal in ["PL", "PLACE"]:
        return "PL"
    elif inVal in ["PARKWAY", "PKWY", "PARKWY"]:
        return "PKWY"
    elif inVal.startswith ("C"):
        return "CT"
"""

#Calculate field
arcpy.CalculateField_management (roadsFC, calcFld,
                                 'Standardize_Road_Type (!{0}!.upper())'.format (anFld),
                                 "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)
```

Good luck! Happy pythoning!

Comment: Thanks Emil for your efforts and sorry for late response. I used this code for my issue.                                  import arcpy
env.workspace = "C:/ArcTutor/geocoding/atlanta.gdb"

# Set local variables:
input_feature_class = "streets"
address_fields = "ID;FULL_STREET_NAME"
locator_style = "US Address-Dual Ranges"
standardized_fields = "PreDir;PreType;StreetName;SufType;SufDir"
standardized_feature_class = "StandardizedStreet"

arcpy.StandardizeAddresses_geocoding(input_feature_class, address_fields, locator_style, standardized_fields, standardized_feature_class, "Static")